# Random sampling elements from two different distributions. Can I find an expression for the ratio of these elements?

Tags: mean, sample

Let's say I have two different distributions. If I take a random sample from one of them $x_1$, and a random sample from the second of them $x_2$, I can compute their ratio as $R = \frac{x_1}{x_2}$. (*Assume that there are no zeros in any of the distributions, or that they can be removed/ignored*).

If I repeat this procedure multiple times, a should come close to an expected ratio $\overline{R}$. Can I find an expression for $\overline{R}$ in terms of the mean and variance of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

My goal is to explore the "contrast" between two regions within a grayscale image, but simply looking at the ratio of their means isn't very informative.

Comment: What do you mean by "masked image" here? To answer your explicit question, we will need to know something about the distributions of xw & xo, eg, dividing by 0 would be undefined. What do you mean by "an expression for $\bar R$? Do you want its sampling distribution?

Comment: I mean a grayscale image which I divide into two regions (of not necessarily the same size). One of the regions I call within the mask, and the other region outside the mask. There are no zeros. I would like to know if the expected ratio can be computed from the first and second moments of the distribution of values within each of the two regions.